# xpath select child nodes whose parent aren't the same type

Tags: xml, xpath

I apologize for the probably misleading title, I didn't know how to phrase it.

I have a huge xml file with lots of elements in it and I need to get a certain element (with the name w:r) but only if that element isn't inside another element with the name w:r

e.g.:

```
<w:r>
    test
</w:r>
```

should select one element

```
<w:r>
    <w:r>
        test
    </w:r>
</w:r>
```

should also select only ONE element (the outer one) and not two.

My current solution is: `//*[local-name()='r']`, but it selects two elements for the second example (one being the outer element and the other being the inner element)

Comment: Is is a direct descendant, or can it be multiple levels of <w:r>?

Comment: there can be multiple levels and it can also be inside another element like for example <w:r><a><b><c>...<w:r>Something</w:r>...</c></b></a></w:r>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the outer `w:r` elements with the following XPath expression:

```
//*[local-name()='r' and not(parent::*[local-name()='r'])]
```

For the following XML (for testing purposes):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root xmlns:w="xxx">
    <w:r t="c">
        test
    </w:r>  
    <w:r t="d">
        <w:r t="h">
            test
        </w:r>
    </w:r>
    <w:r t="e">
        <a>
            <b>
                <c>...
                    <w:r t="i">Something</w:r>
                    ...
                </c>
            </b>
        </a>
    </w:r>
</root>
```

The output is:

```
<w:r xmlns:w="xxx" t="c"/>  
<w:r xmlns:w="xxx" t="d"/>
<w:r xmlns:w="xxx" t="e"/>
```

This means that all the outer `w:r` elements are selected by the expression.

---

If you like to take all parents into account and not just the direct parent, you can use the `ancestor::` axis like this:

```
//*[local-name()='r' and not(ancestor::*[local-name()='r'])]
```

For the example XML, the result is the same, but the semantics are different.